# jslint: why does this code result in a "Strict violation" error message?

Tags: javascript, jslint

Running the following simple code results in a "Strict violation." error message. I have been trying to find documentation on why, and how to fix it. Any input will be much appreciated.

**The error:**

```
Error:

Problem at line 6 character 4: Strict violation.

} (this));
```

**The sample code:**

```
/*jslint browser: true, onevar: true, undef: true, nomen: true, eqeqeq: true, plusplus: true, bitwise: true, regexp: true, strict: true, newcap: true, immed: true */

"use strict";

(function (window) {
} (this));
```

Regards, Egil.

Comment: Relevant? http://twitter.com/kangax/status/8980322050

Comment: KennyTM, it might be, can somebody confirm this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a look at the source code of jslint, which says:

```
function reservevar(s, v) {
    return reserve(s, function () {
        if (this.id === 'this' || this.id === 'arguments' ||
                this.id === 'eval') {
            if (strict_mode && funct['(global)']) {
                warning("Strict violation.", this);
            } else if (option.safe) {
                warning("ADsafe violation.", this);
            }
        }
        return this;
    });
}
```

I guess that jslint really complains that you are using `this` in a global context.

Answer (score 17):

To expand on Roland Illig's answer:

In non-strict mode, `this` is bound to the global scope when it isn't bound to anything else. In strict mode it is undefined. That makes it an error to use it outside of a method.

Comment: `this` still refers to the global scope if used in a global context, but not in methods under strict mode.