# how to remove a function from a loop to make it JSLint compatible?

Tags: javascript, loops, jslint

I'm trying to make a plugin JSLint proof and am struggling with the following error message:

```
Don't make functions within a loop.
```

which complains about this snippet:

```
 for ( i = 0; i < pops.length; i++){
    pops.eq(i)
        .addClass('reverse out '+trans)
        .hide('fast')
        .removeClass('ui-panel-active')
        .find(".ui-page-active")
           .not("div:jqmData(show='first')")
           .removeClass('ui-page-active').end()
        .find(".ui-btn-active")
           .removeClass('ui-btn-active').end()
        .find('div:jqmData(external-page="true")')
           .remove().end().end()
           .delay(350)
           // the problem
           .queue(function(next){
               $(this).removeClass('reverse out pop slide');
                 next();
                 });

            ...
        }
```

I understand where the problem is, but no idea how to make it JSlint-compliant.

**Question:**
How do I get the function out of the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using each()?

Comment: hm. Don't know really. I think I read somewhere to prefer for-loops to each. Is that so? Each sure is easier :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's time to split up this one-liner. It's ridiculously long.

To move your function out of the loop, literally move the function out of the loop:

```
function queue_callback(next) {
    $(this).removeClass('reverse out pop slide');
    next();
}
```

And then replace the anonymous function in the `.queue()` callback with this:

```
.queue(queue_callback)
```

Comment: ya. Thinking about this too :-)

Comment: Agree with the one-liner, you're traversing the DOM constantly on each loop. If you cache the elements you'll get way better performance. Try detaching them do whatever and then inserting them in DOM again.

Comment: ok. Just tried this. I'm getting a `strict` violation, I guess because of `$(this)`, is it?

Comment: `Strict violation` on `$(this).removeClass('reverse out pop slide');`

Comment: @frequent: This seems to be a pitfall of using JSHint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664958/jquery-callback-strict-violation. The error message is somewhat valid, but since you aren't using `queue_callback` outside of this context, the error message isn't really applicable.

Comment: hm. Ok. `JSLint` sure is picky... :-)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can think of is to declare the function outside and pass it as parameter:

```
var queue = function(next) {
  $(this).removeClass('reverse out pop slide');
  next();
};

...

.queue(queue)
```