# What does it mean when I get a strict violation when using the this keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, jslint, strict-mode

Can someone give me advice with this. I just started using jslint and I got an error message "strict violation" pointing to the line with "dialog(this)" -

```
function accessLinkClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.accessLink')
    .unbind('click', accessLinkClick);
    dialog(this);
}

function accessControls() {
    $('.accessLink')
        .bind('click', accessLinkClick);
    $('#logoutLink')
        .click(function (e) {
            window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
        });
}
```

I never saw this message before. what does it mean?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300937/strict-violation-using-this-keyword-and-revealing-module-pattern

Comment: why do you pass `this` do the `dialog()` function? `this` in that case refers to the global object (window) so you don't really need to pass it

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500512/jslint-why-do-this-code-result-in-a-strict-violation-error-message

Comment: @CaffGeek That's a better example than I was able to find

Comment: This post should help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Comment: I don't get that message. Do you get it in your browsers error log?

Comment: @javascriptisfuture the message is received while validating the code with [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Comment: @javascriptisfuture, the OP is likely using "use strict", see: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/

Comment: @VladBalmos keep in mind that he uses `accessControls` as an eventHandler: `.bind('click', accessLinkClick)`. So `this` will be the element that fired the event.

Comment: Yes I am using strict mode. Dialog is a function that I have created. It opens a modal window. I need to pass it the information from the object that was clicked as that has data- attributes that are used when making the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Annex C of the spec explains it as such:

> If `this` is evaluated within strict mode code, then the **this value is not coerced to an object**. A `this` value of `null` or `undefined` is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects. The `this` value passed via a function call (including calls made using Function.prototype.apply and Function.prototype.call) do not coerce the passed `this` value to an object (10.4.3, 11.1.1, 15.3.4.3, 15.3.4.4).

Use `e.target` instead of `this` in the aforementioned code.

**References**

- [Annotated ES5: Annex C](http://es5.github.io/#C)